# How do I only allow a user to submit an html form only once?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am currently making a page for students to create their own groups. Each student has their own unique tutorial group (class name) and group number. Students from different tutorial groups can have the same group number. Each group has 4 members. I need help in making sure that if the group already exists, the user cannot create a new group. Here is how the table in my phpMyadmin looks like:

id| tg | grp | user1 | user2 | user3 | user4 |

tg: tutorial group

grp: group number

user1/2/3/4: group members' name

Below is the relevant code which I tried, but it didn't work.

```
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);


if (mysqli_connect_error()){
die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '
. mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
    $sql = "SELECT (tg,grp) FROM groups";
    $result = $conn-> query($sql);
    if ($result=1){
        print("<script>window.alert('You already have a group');</script>");
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'view_groups.php' ; </script>";
    
    else {
    
    $sql= "INSERT INTO groups (tg, grp, user1, user2, user3, user4) VALUES ('$tg', '$grp','$user1','$user2','$user3','$user4')";
```

Below is the new code which I have tried. This code does not allow new users to create a group. Am I doing something wrong??

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE tg =? AND grp=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $tg, $grp);
$result = $stmt->execute();

if ($result){
    print("<script>window.alert('You already have a group');</script>");
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'view_groups.php' ; </script>";
}

else{

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO groups (tg, grp, user1, user2, user3, user4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $tg, $grp, $user1, $user2, $user3, $user4);
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($result){
print("<script>window.alert('Group is created');</script>");    
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'create_groups.php' ; </script>";
```

Comment: use a session variable

Comment: Why do you abbreviate column names to `tg` and `grp`? You even realize this is bad because you explain them to us. Would `tutorialGroup` and `groupNumber` not be better?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius A session variable would only work if all students use the same computer, and even then, how would that work?

Comment: Incidentally it looks like your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware that is true~ should have read the question fully. The @Op could create a composite unique key using `tg` and `grp` probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code below you try to check if the entered tutorial group and group number already exist, but this doesn't work.

```
$sql = "SELECT (tg,grp) FROM groups";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
if ($result=1) {
    ....
}
```

You need to `SELECT` for the entered tutorial group and group number in the query. Like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM groups WHERE tg = ? AND grp = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $tg, $grp);
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($result) {
    ....
} else {
    printf("Error message: %s\n", $conn->error);
}
```

Note that I bind the parameters to prevent SQL-injection.

However, I have to say that is method is far from perfect. It relies on your students to enter data very accurately, and never make a mistake. That will not work in practice.

Comment: what is the 'ss' for?

Comment: @NoorMuhammad That is explained in the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php Or read a tutorial about this topic here: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-prepared-statements.php

Comment: when I tried the code, I received an error message: 'Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variable doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement'. How do I rectify this problem?

Comment: @NoorMuhammad You have to make sure that the number of question marks in the SQL-query match the number of parameters you bind with `bind_param()`. In my example there are 2 question marks, and 2 parameters `'ss'` in `bind_param()`.

Comment: Thank you for that i realized i made a mistake by using ' before the ?. Now, the code does not have any errors but, if a new user wants to submit the form, it only runs up till the if statement. It does not proceed to the the else statement where the data would be inserted into the database

Comment: Your `INSERT` query looks good. Just write it using a prepared statement, just like I did with the `SELECT` query. See the two links, I gave you earlier, to learn more about this topic.

Comment: I have included the INSERT statement using the prepared statement. You can take a look at it above. Am I doing something wrong? Coz a new user is still not able to create a new group.

Comment: @NoorMuhammad It looks good to me. What is missing is error reporting. I'll add that in my answer, so you can add it to your code. The `$conn->error` lets you know what is wrong. This is different from the normal PHP error messages.

Comment: I already input the $conn->error  like how you have shown me, and no error message pops up, but it still doesn't work. Does this mean that the error is not in the code?

Comment: @NoorMuhammad I think the most likely problem is that, for some reason, the insert query is never executed. This could be due to the complex `if { ... } else if { ....} else { ....}` control flow in your code. As far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with the insert query itself. Also [make sure normal PHP error messages are displayed](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-display-errors-in-php-file) when you work on your code.